# Button positioned at bottom of main div instead of inner Div

Tags: html, css

I have this Register button that needs to be positioned at the bottom of the card, but somehow using position absolute (bottom: 0) places it into the bottom of the main (first) div. Not sure what to do to place it at the bottom of the card:

```
    <STYle>
    .cardHorizontal {
      cursor: default;
      display:inline-block;
      transition: 0.3s;
      width: 40%;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    </STYle>
    <div style="height: 2000px; background-color: #F8F6F7;">
        <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <br><br>
            <!-- Card #1 -->
            <div class="cardHorizontal" style="width: 290px;">
              <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg" style="width:50%; border-radius: 20px; margin: auto; display:block;">
              </a>
              <div class="container">
                <h3><b>Card Title</b></h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum interdum bibendum arcu quis molestie. Duis at pretium justo, at egestas leo. Quisque gravida, est sit amet blandit sagittis, lorem sem iaculis diam, nec facilisis mauris arcu quis orci. Etiam eget ullamcorper ipsum. Maecenas eu nulla ac quam aliquet bibendum vitae vitae est.</p>
                <p style="font-size: 16px"><b>Date: January 2050</b></p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <button style="background-color: #6D925C; color: white; height: 50px; width: 150px; padding: 0; border: none;" type="button">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Try giving the card `position: relative;`